# Proper Page.Loaded event in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, lifecycle

For the past 2 month I have been searching tirelessly for a way to implement a proper `Page.Loaded` event when using Xamarin.Forms but I couldn't implement or find a way to do it.

Most people suggest overriding `Page.OnAppearing` or adding an event handler for `Page.Appearing` both of which are not the answers or the proper way to achieve the desired effect and don't event behave as a real `Page.Loaded` event would.

I would like to know the following:

- Why doesn't Xamarin.Forms have a built-in `Page.Loaded` event?
- Is there's a work around?
- Can I implement it from the native side?

Edit:

What I mean by "proper `Page.Loaded`" event is:

- It must be called ONCE AND ONLY ONCE the page has loaded all of it's controls, laid them out, initialized them and rendered them for the first time.
- It must NOT be called when returning from modal pages.

Comment: how specifically would a "proper" Loaded event behave differently than OnAppearing?  Do either Android or iOS have a native page event that meets your criteria?

Comment: could you try to describe more what you are trying to do? so we could point you on the right direction?

Comment: A proper loaded event would be called only once after the page content has been loaded and initialized (like WPF or UWP or WinForms) not before the content has even appeared or when I return to the page after popping a modal. Yes, Android has OnCreate. I don't work with iOS so I don't know about it.

Comment: @AbdelFattahRadwan I'm well aware of what a page loaded event do, you could try to overrider the LayoutChildren method, although that's not what it's built for, so I would really prefer if you mentioned what you are trying to do

Comment: I didn't mean to say you didn't know, excuse me the comment was meant for @Jason to make what I needed clearer. and LayoutChildren isn't also a solution as it is called multiple times per the page lifecycle...

Comment: "A proper loaded event would be called only once after the page content has been loaded and initialized" - `OnCreate` is called **before** this happens.

Comment: but in `OnCreate` you can call `SetContentView` which allows you to loaded the content and then initialize it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.Why not load the data/controls in the `constructor` of the `ContentPage`? The `constructor` method is call only once and it is also called before `Page.OnAppearing`.

> Can I implement it from the native side?

Yes, I think you can.

In iOS, override the `ViewDidLoad` method in custom renderer:

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer (typeof(ContentPage), typeof(MyPageRenderer))]
namespace App487.iOS
{
    public class MyPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            //call before ViewWillAppear and only called once
        }

        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        }
    }
}
```

In Android, try to override the `OnAttachedToWindow` method:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), typeof(MyPageRenderer))]
namespace App487.Droid
{
    public class MyPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public MyPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }

        protected override void OnAttachedToWindow()
        {
            base.OnAttachedToWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already started putting my initialization code in the constructor until a `Loaded` event is implemented, thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: No problem, you can try the native ways.

Comment: @AbdelFattahRadwan Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 4):

Currently Xamarin.Forms doesn't not provide a proper/complete life cycle events to fulfill all specific requirements, but things are improving, the Dev team is currently working on to address this issue, below mentioned issues and recent pull request on the **official GitHub Repos** (you may follow, get ideas and maybe implement it yourself before they even ship it), they will for sure provide that in the future, although it is not clear when it will be ready.

- Specification: [Enhancement Add better life cycle events #2210](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2210).
- Issue: [LifeCycle events for controls #556](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/556).
- Pull request: [Life cycle events for controls](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/pull/674)
- [GitHub Branch where currently working on](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/tree/pj/Lifecycle-events).
- MAUI repo (Next evolution of Xamarin) [Cross-Platform LifeCycle](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/30).
- Specification [Add Loaded/Unloaded to VisualElement](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8596).